# Date format takes lots of time in for loop

Tags: java, android, performance

I am traversing an arraylist and want to format all the timestamps i get from response but i observed that it takes around 3 seconds to convert 12600 records using DateFormat method and if i use SimpleDateFormat it takes 2 seconds.Strange!!

But I want to decrease this conversion time.

```
ArrayList<String> timestampsList = new ArrayList<String>();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

for(int i=0;i< arraylist.size();i++) {
    cal.setTimeInMillis(arraylist.getTimeStamp());
    timestampsList.add(DateFormat.format("kk:mm", cal).toString());
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in DateFormat method.Finally, i used Joda-Time library to convert my date which took 612 ms only..Awesome improvement.

```
// this one took 612 ms to convert 12600 records   
Joda-Time library 2.3 version

private static final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("kk:mm");
private static DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();

public String getFormattedLabel(long timeStamp) {
    dateTime = dateTime.withMillis(timeStamp);
    return dateTime.toString(dateTimeFormatter);
}
```

and used it like -:

```
ArrayList<String> timestampsList = new ArrayList<String>();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

for(int i=0;i< arraylist.size();
    timestampsList.add(getFormattedLabel(arraylist.getTimeStamp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the static method DateFormat.format(...) - is this an android specific class you are using?

I would assume however that the implementation creates a new format object for the pattern you specify and uses it to format the given calendar.

You could try creating the format object before the loop, see SimpleDateFormat, and then use it inside the loop.

```
int size = arraylist.size();
String[] timestampsList = new String[size];
java.text.DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Date date = arraylist.get(i).??? ;
    timestampsList[i] = format.format(date);
}
```

Note that the format object you created should not be shared between threads so do not store in a static field.

Also note that Calendar calculations might also be computation intensive, it could be that this is also slowing things down, but if you use SimpleDateFormat directly you can just use raw dates.

You might want also to set the timezone on your format object.

Comment: THanks RonP...But it is not helping i tried setting timezone too.

Comment: Try using apache commons lang FastDateFormat - if it does help, you could try to copy the sources and include only the classes you need, to not bust your app size, if that mutters.